# How do I drop all numbers as data cleansing on pandas effectively?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

Here's my dataset

```
id                                             descriptions
0                       kartu debit 20 10 indomaretcipete r
1                                         tarikan atm 20 10
2                                         tarikan atm 19 10
3                                                 biaya adm
4                       trsf 18 10 wsid 23881 indah lestari
```

Here's what I did

```
def cleaning(text):
    stops = {'10', '18','19', '20', '23881'}
    text = [word for word in text if not word in stops]
    text = " ".join(text)
return(text)

df['description_clean'] = df['description'].apply(cleaning)
```

Here's what I got

```
  id                                              descriptions
  0                             kartu debit indomaretcipete r
  1                                               tarikan atm
  2                                               tarikan atm
  3                                                 biaya adm
  4                                   trsf wsid indah lestari
```

This is not effective I keep add new numbers to improve stopwords, how do in one time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) and [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
df['descriptions'] = (df['descriptions'].str.extractall('([a-zA_Z]+)')
                                        .groupby(level=0).agg({0:' '.join}))
```

Or:

```
df['descriptions'] = (df['descriptions'].str.replace('\d+','')
                                        .str.replace('  ',''))
```

Or:

```
df['descriptions'] = [' '.join(re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+',s)) for s in df['descriptions']]
```

---

```
print(df)
   id                   descriptions
0   0  kartu debit indomaretcipete r
1   1                    tarikan atm
2   2                    tarikan atm
3   3                      biaya adm
4   4        trsf wsid indah lestari
```

Comment: Best answer so far, but too slow

Comment: @NabihBawazir String Operations in pandas are generally slow. Check other solutions if they speed up the process.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you need to remove numbers from the dataframe, use below:

```
df_new=df.replace('\d+ ','',regex=True)
print(df_new)

   id                   descriptions
0   0  kartu debit indomaretcipete r
1   1                 tarikan atm 10
2   2                 tarikan atm 10
3   3                      biaya adm
4   4        trsf wsid indah lestari
```

For just one series: `df['descriptions']=df['descriptions'].replace('\d+ ','',regex=True)`

Note: i have added a space after `d+` in the regex depending on your example, you can do without it if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
def replace_numbers(s):
    return re.sub(r'\d*', '', s)


df['description'] = df['description'].apply(replace_numbers)
```